# How can i only add to a list if it doesnt exist using lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am using

```
  myObject.UserObject.Any = (myObject.UserObject.Any ?? Enumerable.Empty<XmlElement>())
 .Concat(new[] { GetNewXmlElement(addressObject.Street, columnsObject.First(t => t.Key 
 == columnsObject.Name).Value, false, columnsObject.Name) }).ToArray();
```

what this does is just add the value to the end of myObject even if there is one exactly the same in the list , ie it gives duplicates.

How can i only add if there isnt one already in the list by checking Street Value in the Name node of the xml ?

Comment: `.Union` with the appropriate comparer? Though if you're going that route, why not use a `HashSet<XmlElement>` with the appropriate comparer instead, do away with the LINQ (which makes it more confusing) and simply call `.Add`?

Comment: is there an example with this ?

Comment: Why making it so complicated? Using an if statement to check if the object not exists and then adding it would be way better to read.